# event is null when using isClearable on react-select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-select

I am passing through the react-select Select component as an InputComponent within the Material-UI InputBase component. I have successfully been able to populate the value from the options, however, I'm unable to use `isClearable`.

When isClearable is triggered, null is passed to the `handleChange(event)` function and I'm hoping there is a way to force an object through to prevent null creating an error.

The handleChange function within InputBase has `var element = event.target || inputRef.current`. As event is null, it's not even getting to inputRef which will contain the required object.

Would be good to get this working as an uncontrolled component.

I have created a codebox to illustrate the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-feather-l7xqf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could supply your custom `onChange()` to catch the `null` and pass through your own value:

```js
// Deconstruct from otherProps
const SelectWrapper = ({ inputRef, onChange, ...otherProps }) => {
  
  function handleChange(event) {
    // Overwrite the event with your own object if it doesn't exist
    if (!event) {
      event = {
        target: inputRef,
        value: '',
      };
    }
    onChange(event);
  }
  
  return (
    // Pass in the custom handleChange
    <Select styles={customStyle} isClearable ref={inputRef} onChange={handleChange} {...otherProps} />
  );
};
```

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes! Thank you!

Comment: the second argument of handleChange() contains an object with an `action` prop. It's set to "clear" when you clear it.

Comment: @Marc's comment was the actual life saver for me

Comment: Hey @Marc thank you for providing the correct solution!